# Django DRF: Take extra input from user using serializer but not present in the model

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I have one `ModelSerializer` class which is used for user input & validation. I am using it with a ModelViewset which automatically creates a new entry in the database using the serializer. Now what I want to do is that I want to have a extra field in the serializer say `roles` which will be given by the user. It is an array of roles  for a user but this field is not present in the model & I want to manually add this roles entry in the `auth_user_groups` table. So I wrote my serializer like this,

```
class UserCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    Serializer to create new user
    """
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ["name", "email", "is_active", "roles"]
        read_only_fields = ['roles']
        
    roles = serializers.MultipleChoiceField(choices=[(e.name,e.value) for e in AuthGroup])
        
    
    def validate_roles(self, value):
        
        if not value:
            raise ValidationError(detail=constants.NAMED_FIELD_REQUIRED.format(field="roles"))
```

My model looks like this,

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    class Meta:
        db_table = "auth_user"
        app_label = "users"

    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)

    email = models.EmailField("email address", unique=True, null=True)

    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    is_superuser = None

    is_admin = None

    is_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name or self.email

    def is_admin(self):
        return self.groups.filter(name=AuthGroup.ADMIN.name).exists()
```

This is the request body which is coming from user.

```
{
  "name": "test4",
  "email": "test4@example.com",
  "is_active": true,
  "roles": [
    "ADMIN", "OPERATOR"
  ]
}
```

So I get this error whenever I try to call the API,

> raise TypeError("%s() got an unexpected keyword argument '%s'" %
> (cls.**name**, kwarg)) TypeError: User() got an unexpected keyword
> argument 'roles'

So anyone have any idea how can I solve this or achieve what I have said above? Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the validated data is getting passed to the `create(...)` method of `QuerySet` inside the `create(...)` method of the serializer. So, you need to pop the `roles` field before the creation operation.

```
class UserCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ["name", "email", "is_active", "roles"]

    roles = serializers.MultipleChoiceField(
        choices=[(e.name, e.value) for e in AuthGroup],
        required=True,
        write_only=True
    )

    def validate_roles(self, value):
        # do some validations
        return value

    def create(self, validated_data):
        roles = validated_data.pop("roles", None)
        return super().create(validated_data)
```

### Notes

- You can use `required=True` to set the field as mandatory so that you don't have to do any extra validations for that
- `read_only_fields` will work for those fields which are *not* defined explicitly in the serializer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did what you said but now getting this different error,
AttributeError at /users/
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `roles` on serializer `UserCreateSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `User` instance.
Original exception text was: 'User' object has no attribute 'roles'.

Comment: oops - forgot to add `write_only=True` argument. See the updated answer

Comment: thanks....it is working now.